# SSL Certificate where to install when DNS A direct to Virtual host on different server?

Tags: ssl, dns, webserver

I want to move a client's website to another faster server. Because of their mail server this will happen via DNS A entry.

On which server does the SSL certificate need to be installed? The one doing the DNS redirect or the one with the virtual host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be installed at the virtual host. Basically on the server whose ip address you are putting in the A record of your domain.

Answer (score 0):

We suggest you, as you are planning to moving your website to another server, the SSL should be installed on new server's virutal host.

As you are having IP based virtual hosting, the A record should point to the new refered the host should be redirected dedictated ip (as in A record entry) in parent DNS.

For subdomain zone-the parent DNS should have entry to point the new name server, the NS record should be also created to refer the subdomains's DNS server zone.